# Constructing bipartite network from csv file using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, networkx, bipartite

I have an edgelist of csv file that represents a bipartite network. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjz9v.png)

The first column represents individuals, and the second column represents firms in which those individuals work for.

I am constructing a bipartite network based on this, to get each individual's network attributes such as centrality. Below is what I got.

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import csv
    with open("data.csv") as infile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(infile)
    G = nx.Graph(csv_reader) 
print(G.nodes())
```

From here, I have no idea what to do next. Could you please help me?

Comment: 61 appears in both columns. Are the two 61s different? Otherwise the graph does not appear to be bipartite.

Comment: @fuglede Yes. The numbers in the two columns means different (i.e. 1st column for an individual, 2nd column for a firm).

Answer (score 0):

Nodes are created automatically if you pass the edgelist.
A way consists in passing through `pandas` and use the [from_pandas_edgelist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) method.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'FD_ID', 'FH_ID')
```